# Django Manager.values() returns a mysterious None

Tags: python, mysql, django-admin, nonetype

**Django 1.7.1, MySQL 5.6, Python 2.7.8**

I have a class `Test` with a few thousand member objects. It inherits just time, date and id from a concrete base class. The Test class contains an attribute corresponding to a non-nullable column. Let's call it `color`. When I run

```
Test.objects.filter(date=date).values('color').distinct()
```

it dutifully returns a list of singleton dicts that looks like

```
[{'color': None}, {'color': u'yellow'}, {'color': u'clear'}, ... ]
```

Indeed,

```
>>> Test.objects.filter(date=date).count()
1650
>>> Test.objects.filter(date=date, color=None).count()
1650
>>> Test.objects.filter(date=date, color='clear').count()
4
```

These return values appear to contradict since of the 1650 total objects from the given date, all of them have the color `None`, yet 4 of them have the color 'clear'. Other colors return good int values as well, and examination of the DB confirms that they are correct and that there are no `None`s at all in that column.

The presence of the `None` is causing me troubles elsewhere, when the program iterates over the values and gets a KeyError.

Does `values()` somehow trivially include the `None` even though it is neither a real value for any object nor even possible?

Why is that `None` there?

What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Is the color field actually on that model, or is it a FK or M2M to another model?

Comment: It's not possible to tell from the code provided, but maybe you have an order_by problem? If your ordering is based on a related model, that could explain how you're seeing None values on a non-nullable field. See this note from the docs about combining values() and distinct(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's on that model. But now that you mention it, the date field _is_ a foreign key. Could that be related?

Comment: @dylrei So I'm not explicitly ordering by anything, but I suppose there could be an implicit one somewhere. Can you explain the "that could explain how you're seeing None values on a non-nullable field"? I've read that section and that note, but I don't see how it pertains to the results I got, other than the catch-all "unexpected results". In that case I still don't understand _how_ or _why_ this would happen. Thanks! What other information should I include to help answer this?

Comment: @WAF Your code is interacting with objects, but those objects are executing SQL code. Even though you are only interested in seeing one column, your underlying SQL might be using a join... so then, even though you're suppressing most of the columns, you're looking at effects created by more than one column. Print both of these to console and see what you get:   Test.objects.filter(date=date, color=None).query   Test.objects.filter(date=date).values('color').distinct().query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If date is a foreign key (per the comments), that's likely the source of your problem.

I expect that the underlying query is filtering first on the "one" side of this relationship and some of those records are unmatched on the "many" side. Those unmatched records are part of your initial result set, thus you get a None for the color for some number of rows.

It's a bit of a kludge, but you can exclude those unmatched records this way:

```
Test.objects.filter(date=date).exclude(color=None).values('color').distinct()
```

Or maybe it's time to take another look at your model design. Tough to know from here.

Comment: Indeed, the revealed SQL shows that there is an INNER JOIN of the child and parent tables, resulting in as many rows as the _parent_ slice contains, with NULLs on rows with other object types. And your exclude() solution does work by adding a WHERE...NOT clause at the end. Would the SQL run faster if that condition were in a SELECT subquery? (Assume that the parent:child ratio is high.) Thanks!

Comment: @WAF I wouldn't expect a big difference, but I don't know much about how this is implemented. You could always just try a few different strategies and time the response. Might also try DateModel.objects.filter(date=date).test_set and see if that works any better (not sure what your "date" model is called).